# How create a bottom navigation bar which starts at page item1 and not at item0

Tags: flutter

What I mean is that the page1 should open when application is launched

My code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main()
{
  runApp(
   MyApp()
  );
}
class MyApp  extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(

    );
  }
}


class MyBottomNavigationBar  extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyBottomNavigationBarState createState() => _MyBottomNavigationBarState();
}

class _MyBottomNavigationBarState extends State<MyBottomNavigationBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(

    );
  }
}
```

this is where page is opened:
[image: this is where page is opened]

this is where I want to open my page:
[image: this is where I want to open my page]

Comment: You should have specified the index as default in your code. You should update it to index 1 instead of 0. If you can't figure out add your complete minimal code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out

**Code 1**

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
        return MyAppState();
      }
    }
    
    class MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{
    
      int _selectedPage = 1;
      final _pageOptions = [
        Text('Item1'),
        Text('Item2'),
        Text('Item3')
      ];
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Demo',
    
          theme: ThemeData(
              primaryColor: Colors.blueAccent,
             
          ),
    
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title:Text("Demo"),
              //backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
    
            body: _pageOptions[_selectedPage],
    
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    
                //fixedColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
    
                currentIndex: _selectedPage,
                onTap: (int index){
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedPage= index;
                  });
                },
                items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search), title: Text('Players'),backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Trending'),backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.access_time), title: Text('Highlights'),backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent)
                ]
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

**Code 2**

With using this package [Presistant_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar).so you can use bottomnavbar on every screen or you can do the above method

```
    PersistentTabController _controller =PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 1);
    
    //Screens for each nav items.
      List<Widget> _NavScreens() {
        return [
         
         OfferScreen(),
         
         HelpScreen(),
         HomeScreen(),    
         ProfileScreen(),
         CartViewScreen(),
          
        ];
      }
    
    
      List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
        return [
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
           icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: ("Home"),
            activeColor: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
            inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
          ),
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            title: ("OFFERS"),
            activeColor: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
            inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
          ),
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person_pin),
            title: ("Help"),
            activeColor: CupertinoColors.systemRed,
            inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
          ),
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.local_activity),
            title: ("ProfileScreen"),
            activeColor: CupertinoColors.systemIndigo,
            inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
          ),
     PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shop_cart),
            title: ("Cart"),
            activeColor: CupertinoColors.systemIndigo,
            inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
          ),
    
        ];
      }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: PersistentTabView(
            controller: _controller,
            screens: _NavScreens(),
            items: _navBarsItems(),
            confineInSafeArea: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
            hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
            decoration: NavBarDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
            navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style9,
          ),
        );
    }
```

Also you can use navigation bottombar in certain screen by using navigator-functions instead of flutter navigator.push();
for more details checkout [persistent_bottom_nav_bar#navigator-functions](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar#navigator-functions)

```
pushNewScreen(
        context,
        screen: MainScreen(),
        withNavBar: true, // OPTIONAL VALUE. True by default.
        pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope it helps to you ,just selected index is **1**

```
class BottomNavigationBarScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavigationBarScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BottomNavigationBarScreenState createState() =>
      _BottomNavigationBarScreenState();
}

class _BottomNavigationBarScreenState extends State<BottomNavigationBarScreen> {
  int _selectedIndex = 1;
  final List<Widget> _screens = [
    Center(child:Text('Screen One'),),
    Center(child:Text('Screen Two'),),
    Center(child:Text('Screen Three'),),
    Center(child:Text('Screen Four'),),
    
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _screens[_selectedIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: (value) {
          setState(() => _selectedIndex = value);
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
            ),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            label: 'Search',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            label: 'My Cart',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Account',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man I see now where my problem was